# How to create Ajax based multiple file selector uploader?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, flash, file-upload

**Hello Guys!**

---

I want to create a site with a multiple file uploading through a singe button. And as I'm very new to the world of Web-Based Scripts, can anyone provide me a link to get my answer?

---

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly go to the below link and you get the answer for your question. In this link their is Ajax and Flash based script which allows your users to select multiple files on single button. Or you can just search it in Google. (Just for hint : ajax upload script)

[CODE INFO LINK](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

[CODE DOWNLOAD LINK](https://download.github.com/valums-file-uploader-0c701eb.zip) (GITHUB)

Comment: Thanks buddy this is what I was looking for! Thanks once again.